# Передача параметров через сигнал QT своим классом

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Как я понял проблема в том что через сигнал передаётся содержимое пользовательского класса. Использование Q_DECLARE_METATYPE в прототипе класса выводило ошибку. Как мне передать данные в данном случае?

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::setMail(SetMail*&)'
   emit this->setMail(set); // настроить письмо
                         ^

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

signals:
  void setMail(SetMail); 
};

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStart_clicked()
{
  SetMail *set = new SetMail(this);

  set->provider = prov->nowProvider();
  set->sender = "";

  emit this->setMail(set); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  TransportMail *tm = new TransportMail();

  QObject::connect(&w, SIGNAL(setMail(SetMail)), tm, SLOT(setMail(SetMail)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В объявлении сигнала передается объект:

```
signals:
    void setMail(SetMail);
```

А при попытке передачи вы пытаетесь передать указатель:

```
SetMail *set = new SetMail(this);
...
emit this->setMail(set);
```

Надо исправить объявление сигнала на

```
signals:
    void setMail(SetMail *);
```

И не забыть исправить принимающий слот